# Converting a piece of code to use java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code and I wanted to know if it is possible to get the same code done in java streams:

Input class:

```
public class Car {
    Long carNum;
    String carEngine;
    int carCode;
    int carName;
    String cartype;
}
```

output data of type: `Map<Integer, Output>`

output class:

```
class Output {
    Long carNum;
    String carCode;
    String carNameWithEngine;
    String carChasisInfo;
}
```

The sample input data looks like this:

```
[Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S02K, carCode=553, carName=1, cartype=Sedan), Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S43D, carCode=679, carName=1, cartype=Hatchback), Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S43A, carCode=678, carName=1, cartype=MPV), Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S22K, carCode=553, carName=3, cartype=Truck), Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S27K, carCode=553, carName=5, cartype=Van), Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S19K, carCode=53, carName=7, cartype=SUV), Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S9K, carCode=63, carName=9, cartype=Truck-LD), Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S21K, carCode=653, carName=3, cartype=Truck), Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S29K, carCode=6543, carName=5, cartype=Van), Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S14K, carCode=654, carName=7, cartype=SUV), Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S2K, carCode=553, carName=9, cartype=Truck-LD)]
```

The output should in the following way:

```
{1=Output(carNum=0, carInfo=S02K,S43D, carNameWithEngine=S43A_1,S19K_7, carChasisInfo=S22K_3,S27K_5), 2=Output(carNum=2, carInfo=, carNameWithEngine=S14K_7, carChasisInfo=S9K_9,S21K_3,S29K_5,S2K_9)}
```

I have to map all the data by carNum and concatenating the fields based on the following values:

```
Set<String> sedanQualifierSet = Set.of("Sedan","Hatchback");
Set<String> suvQualifierSet = Set.of("SUV","MPV");
Set<String> truckQualifierSet = Set.of("Van","Truck","Truck-LD");
```

i.e., if the cartype is either Sedan or Hatchback then I should be concatenating the carCode values of the same carNum with a comma (,)
if the cartype is either SUV or MPV then I should be first concatenating the carCode to carName using underscore (-) and then concatenate values of the same carNum with a comma (,)
if the cartype is either Van or Truck or Truck-LD then I should first concatenating carCode to carName using underscore (_) and then concatenate values of the same carNum with a comma (,)

I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
Map<Long, Output> carInfo = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long, List<Car>> collect = cdList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCarNum, Collectors.toList()));
        
for (Entry<Long, List<Car>> cd : collectList.entrySet()) {
        Output output = new Output();
        for (Car car : cd.getValue()) {
            if (sedanQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
                output.setCarCode(
                        String.join(",", output.getCarCode(), car.getCarEngine()));
            } else if (suvQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
                output.setCarNameWithEngine(String.join(",", output.getCarNameWithEngine(),
                        car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName()));
            } else if (truckQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
                output.setCarChasisInfo(String.join(",", output.getCarChasisInfo(),
                        car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName()));
            }
            output.setCarNum(cd.getKey());
        }
        carInfo.put(cd.getKey(), output);
}
```

I wanted to achieve the same functionality using java streams.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `getClaimKey`? `claimKey` is not in your input data? What does `setCarCode` do? The output does not have a `carCode` field.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it with the correct ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think turning this into purely Stream APIs would not improve the code at all. It would make it a lot less readable, a lot longer, and probably a lot slower.

You seem to be splitting each group into 3 smaller groups and processing each differently, and streams are particularly bad at that.

Anyway, using `String.join` is probably not what you want (?) Assuming each of the `String`s in `Output` starts off as null, using `String.join` like that would create a leading `null,`. I would write my own `join` that behaves more desirably:

```
private static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}

private static String join(String separator, String s1, String s2) {
    if (isNullOrEmpty(s1)) {
        return s2;
    }
    if (isNullOrEmpty(s2)) {
        return s1;
    }
    return s1 + separator + s2;
}
```

or add `appendXXX` methods to `Output` to handle this directly in `Output`.

If you really want to use streams, I would just create a custom `Collector` with `Collector.of`.

```
var collector = Collector.of(
    Output::new,
    (Output output, Car car) -> {
        output.setCarNum(car.getCarNum());
        if (sedanQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
            output.setCarCode(join(",", output.getCarCode(), String.valueOf(car.getCarCode())));
        } else if (suvQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
            output.setCarNameWithEngine(join(",", output.getCarNameWithEngine(),
                car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName()));
        } else if (truckQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype())) {
            output.setCarChasisInfo(join(",", output.getCarChasisInfo(),
                car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName()));
        }
    },
    (o1, o2) -> {
        var newOutput = new Output();
        newOutput.setCarNum(o1.getCarNum()); // o1.carNum is the same as o2.carNum
        // using the custom join method here
        newOutput.setCarCode(join(",", o1.getCarCode(), o2.getCarCode()));
        newOutput.setCarNameWithEngine(join(",", o1.getCarNameWithEngine(), o2.getCarNameWithEngine()));
        newOutput.setCarChasisInfo(join(",", o1.getCarChasisInfo(), o2.getCarChasisInfo()));
        return newOutput;
    }
);
```

You can see that this is basically your if-else-ifs, with an additional combiner lambda, because collectors need that.

Then you can use this as the downstream of `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Long, Output> result = cdList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCarNum, collector)
);
```

While it is also possible to split the stream up with the built-in collector `teeing`, the code gets really convoluted:

```
cdList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCarNum,
        Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.mapping(Car::getCarNum,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        // every car num is the same, so just take the first one
                        Collectors.reducing((x, y) -> x),
                        // there is guaranteed to be at least one car num
                        Optional::get
                    )
                ),
                Collectors.filtering(car -> sedanQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype()),
                    Collectors.mapping(car -> Integer.toString(car.getCarCode()),
                        Collectors.joining(",")
                        )
                    ),
                Output::fromCarNumCarCode
            ),
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.filtering(car -> suvQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype()),
                    Collectors.mapping(car -> car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName(),
                        Collectors.joining(","))
                ),
                Collectors.filtering(car -> truckQualifierSet.contains(car.getCartype()),
                    Collectors.mapping(car -> car.getCarEngine() + "_" + car.getCarName(),
                        Collectors.joining(","))
                ),
                Output::fromCarNameWithEngineCarChasisInfo
            ),
            Output::combine
        )
    )
);
```

I have used some helper methods, which I have put in `Output`, for creating intermediate `Output` objects in the above code (these could be inlined as lambdas, but that just makes the code even longer).

```
public static Output fromCarNumCarCode(Long carNum, String carCode) {
    var output = new Output();
    output.setCarNum(carNum);
    output.setCarCode(carCode);
    return output;
}

public static Output fromCarNameWithEngineCarChasisInfo(String carNameWithEngine, String carChasisInfo) {
    var output = new Output();
    output.setCarNameWithEngine(carNameWithEngine);
    output.setCarChasisInfo(carChasisInfo);
    return output;
}

public static Output combine(Output o1, Output o2) {
    var output = new Output();
    output.setCarNum(o1.getCarNum());
    output.setCarCode(o1.getCarCode());
    output.setCarNameWithEngine(o2.getCarNameWithEngine());
    output.setCarChasisInfo(o2.getCarChasisInfo());
    return output;
}
```